# Future.onComplete: can't understand the method signature

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

```
  /** When this future is completed, either through an exception, or a value,
   *  apply the provided function.
   *
   *  If the future has already been completed,
   *  this will either be applied immediately or be scheduled asynchronously.
   *
   *  $multipleCallbacks
   *  $callbackInContext
   */
  def onComplete[U](func: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

Basic usage seems to be:

```
  result.onComplete({
    case Success(listInt) => {
      //Do something with my list
    }
    case Failure(exception) => {
      //Do something with my error
    }
  })
```

This function seems useful to produce side effects as it returns Unit (like logging completion)
What I don't understand is what is this type `U` that the function returns. Is the return type of the function we provide really useful? How is it used by Scala?

The same question could apply to `onSuccess` and `onFailure`

**Edit:** to make it clearer, what's the benefits of `def onComplete[U](func: Try[T] => U)` over `def onComplete(func: Try[T] => Unit)`?

---

**Edit**:

Chirlo is right, the function with type U is more flexible and we can pass it more easily existing functions that do not return Unit.

```
type T = String

def onComplete[U](func: Try[T] => U): Unit = { }
def onComplete2(func: Try[T] => Unit): Unit = { }

// Existing function that does not return Unit
def log[T]( t : Try[T]): Int = 0

onComplete(log) // This compiles fine
onComplete2(log) // This does not compile
```

Comment: [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) best place for futures and promises

Comment: yes @GKV I've took a glance at the `Callbacks` section and it didn't help me much as the usage of type `U` does not seem to be described

Comment: Let's suppose you already have function `val op: Try[Int] => Sting`. With `[U]` you can use it like this: `onComplete(op)`. Without `[U]` you'll have to use it this way: `onComplete(op(_))` (additional anonymous function).

Comment: I can't tell you the right answer for this but I think the `U` type parameter might exist because an implementation of the `Future` trait might actually use the result of the partial function (which is not the case for the "default implementations" to my knowledge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the function more flexible. If it would return `Unit`, you could just pass it functions `Try[T] => Unit`, but by returning `U`, you can pass it any function that takes `Try[T]` as a parameter, that you may already have lying around. For example:

```
def log[T]( t : Try[T]): Int =  //write to file and return 0  if Ok, else 128
```

This functions has side effects but also returns a value. You can now pass this function to your `Future` although it doesn't return `Unit`, the result is thrown away but you can reuse an already existing function.

Comment: Yes you are write, I gave some explaiinations in my own question

Answer (score 0):

a very simple example should clear the cloud

```
val a = Future(1/2)
a.onComplete[String]({
  case Success(1) => "StringValue"         
})
```

here ***U*** is String and ***T*** is Int in the Success.

Now in most of the cases scala understands what is the data type and we need not to specifically mention the type U and T

the above example will result into an error if we change String "StringValue" to something else

```
val a = Future(1/2)
a.onComplete[String]({
  case Success(1) => 1
})
```

compilation error- ***type mismatch; found : Int(1) required: String***

if however we remove String from complete and not forcing return type as String, it will take any type

```
val a=Future(1/2)
a.onComplete({
  case Success(1)=>1
  case Success(2) => "we found two"  
  case Success(3) => 1.0f
  case Success(_) => new RuntimeException("it was not expected")
})
```

***compiles fine.*** and hence gives us power of returning multiple types depending upon your usecase

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your point. I know what this compilation error is, just don't understand the point of enforcing compilation rules on a function that just produce side effects

Comment: i have edited the last e.g. above, hoping this should help.

U if helpful if you want to restrict the output types and when omitted, you have the leverage of outputting anything that might fall into your cases.
hope this should help!!

Comment: Like Sebastien, I don't really understand the point of this answer. `a.onComplete[Any]` also compiles fine under your example.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Any will of course work.
If you go through [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/images/classhierarchy.img_assist_custom.png) link, you can see that Any is at the top of the hierarchy.
Point is if you want to restrict the output type, you use U provided in the signature.

Comment: Sure, but your example does not illustrate *why* you would want to restrict the output type.

Comment: This basically circumvents the already weak Scala typechecker